# When using WebRTC, is a peer-to-peer architecture redundant to build a video chat service like Skype?

Tags: html, webkit, skype, webrtc

We're playing around with WebRTC and trying to understand its benefits.

One reason Skype can serve hundreds of millions of people is because of its decentralized, peer-to-peer architecture, which keeps server costs down.

Does WebRTC allow people to build a video chat application similar to Skype in that the architecture can be decentralized (i.e., video streams are not routed from a broadcaster through a central server to listeners but rather routed directly from broadcaster to listener)?

Or, put another way, does WebRTC allow someone to essentially replicate the benefits of a P2P architecture similar to Skype's?

Or do you still need something similar to Skype's P2P architecture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's basically what WebRTC does. Calls using the getPeerConnection() API don't send voice/video data through a centralized server, but rather use firewall traversal protocols like ICE, STUN and TURN to allow a direct, peer-to-peer connection. However, the initial call setup still requires a server (most likely something running a WebSocket implementation, but it could be anything that you can figure out how to get JavaScript to talk to), so that the two clients can figure out that they're both online, signal that they want to connect, and then figure out how to do it (this is where the ICE/STUN/TURN bit comes in).

However, there's more to Skype's P2P architecture than just passing voice/video data back and forth. The majority of Skype's IP isn't in the codecs or protocols (much of which they licensed from Global IP Solutions, which Google purchased two years ago and then open-sourced, and which forms of the basis of Chrome's WebRTC implementation). Skype's real IP is all in the piece of WebRTC which still depends on a server: figuring out which people are online, and where they are, and how to get a hold of them, and doing *that* in a massively decentralized fashion. (See [here](http://www.slideshare.net/Sandra4211/voip-skype-architecture) for some rough details.) I think that you could probably use the [DataStream](http://www.w3.org/2011/04/webrtc/wiki/images/e/e0/WebRTCDataStreamsIETF82.5.pdf) portion of the getPeerConnection() API to do that sort of thing, if you were really, really smart - but it would be complicated, and would most likely stomp on a few Skype patents. Unless you want to be really, really huge, you'd probably just want to run your own centralized presence and location servers and handle all that stuff through standard WebSockets.

Answer (score 1):

I should note that Skype's network architecture has changed since it was created; it no longer (from what I hear) uses random users as supernodes to relay data from client 1 to client 2; it didn't scale well and caused rampant variability in results (and annoyed people who had non-firewalled connections and bandwidth).

You definitely can build something SKype-like with WebRTC - and more.  :-)